# How can I connect a sensor to two LEDs so that one will work when the sensor's output is HIGH and the other when it's LOW?

Tags: led

(Moved from the Arduino stackexchange)

Let OUT be the sensor's output.

If I connect

LED1 to BAT+ and OUT

LED2 to BAT- and OUT

is this Ok? 
[image]

Instead of LEDs those could be units that need even less current. I am also interested to know the limits of the offered solution in terms of current and what should I do from units that draw higher current.

Anyway, I look for a solution without a MCU.

Comment: Your question is confusing. Please draw a schematic of your existing circuit using the built-in schematic editor. Also, please clarify your title...what does the pronoun "it" refer to? Sensor? One of the LEDs?

Comment: Edit your answer. Type "Ctrl-M" (control M)-> this opens the schematic editor. Play. It's marvellous and 'almost self teaching'.  Click the appropriate button to save to question when finished.

Comment: Which sensor do you want to use?

Comment: @BruceAbbott It depends. The OUT could be a proximity sensor or a NE555

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your solution is acceptable within limitations:

- Voltage swing of Out needs to be >= Vf = LED on voltage (no surprise)
- Vsupply needs to be much less than Vf (LED on voltage). If Vsupply is too high both LEDs will light noticeably when OUT is open circuit.
  In almost any real-world case you will get some LED current when OUT is open circuit. This may or may not be acceptable.
- OUT needs to be able to source and sink the required LED current.
- A resistor is provided between the centre point of the two LEDS and OUT to control LED current.

R1 is sized to suit desired LED current drain.

More can be said but start with the above and ask/comment as required.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fjvi65.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

**___________________________**

For higher current than the I/O pin can source or sink a buffer or driver is required.   This can be an IC suited to the task or a discrete transistor circuit.

This circuit will work "as shown" with some limitations.
Q1 / Q2 draw a current spike at changeover from high to low and VOUT should not be left open-circuit.
Q1 / Q2 can be any small bipolar transistor with adequate voltage and current characteristrics.
R1 is sized to suit desired LED current drain.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fhMoBq.png)</sup>

Comment: Thanks.This is very informative!!
What happens if I replace the LEDs with LCDs? Can I eliminate the current from flowing through both of them (without MCU)?

Comment: 1. "An LCD" is not very well defined. what do you means? A whole mukti digit display or a single dot or area annunciator or ...? 2. The current will flow through both (if ever) ONLY when Vout is floatig. If Vout is low LED1 is on. If Vout is high LED2 is on. If Vout is open circuit/floting LED1 + LED2 are across the supply. With eg white LEDS and a 5V supply you will get 2.5V/LED and some illumination. How much depends on the LEDs used.

Comment: I mean one LCD light valve - one unit, not a 1602.

Answer (score 3):

[image]

*Figure 1. Source: [One GPIO, multiple LEDs](http://lednique.com/gpio-tricks/1-gpio-multiple-leds/).*

- When the output is switched low current will flow from the positive supply via R1 and the L1, green, to the output pin. L1 will illuminate. L2, red, will be shorted out and will be dark.
- When the output is switched high current will flow from the pin through R2 and L2. The red LED will illuminate and the green will be dark.
- If the output is tri-stated (wired as an input or disconnected by program control) a current will flow through R1, L1, R2, L2 and both LEDs will glow dimly. On a 3.3 V device the voltage wouldn’t be high enough to illuminate both LEDs significantly so they would appear dark.
- By rapidly (> 25 Hz should be enough) alternately switching the output high and low while varying the duty-cycle a cross-fade effect can be given.

See the linked article for more on the subject.

Comment: Beautiful! What can you do if you replace the LEDs by motors that draw current more then the GPIO can take?

Comment: That's a different question. Ask a new one but you'd need to explain what you're really doing and give motor specifications and estimated maximum currents and voltages along with details of what exactly is driving it. Also specify whether or not reversing is required.

Comment: Why there's no current all the time from 5V to GND through the two LEDs?

Comment: Because when the output is high R1 + L1 is shorted out. When the output is low R2 + L2 is shorted out.

Comment: I didn't just 'copy' your answer . I wrote the 1st half of mine then it got left unposted overnight (antipodean). "Great minds think alike :-) ) (Yes, it's obvious, but ... . )

Comment: You must make sure the sum of the minimum forward voltage drop across both LEDs is larger than the 5V.

Comment: No problem, @Russell. I know your style well enough to know that wouldn't be your intention. You've done a variation anyway and added some other details. Thanks.

Comment: @DKN: I think I covered that in the third bullet point.

Comment: @Transistor I guess it does. I was thinking of a slightly different version of the circuit where there is a common resistor for both LEDs rather than individual resistors where it is an issue even if the output is not tri-stated.

Comment: Russell's got it covered.